# Problem downloading files from Filestore in Databricks

Tags: azure-databricks

I ran into a problem where the link to download files from the Filestore in Databricks no longer works. I had scripts that would print out the link and I could download the files. This is the format I used to download: https:///files/my-stuff/my-file.txt?o=######

I followed the steps from the [Filestore official documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dbfs/filestore.html#:%7E:text=your%20Databricks%20deployment.-,Files%20stored%20in,-/FileStore%20are%20accessible), but I'm still having issues.

DBR 12.2 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.3.2, Scala 2.12)

Please let me know if you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue, and it was resolved by using `https://<databricks-instance>/files/my-stuff/my-file.txt` for the URL format, regardless of whether or not the deployment URL includes `?o=######` at the end. (Not sure why this happens, though.)